# Why did the Targaryens renege the Pact of Ice and Fire?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In the Dance of the Dragons, in exchange for Cregan Stark's support, the (Black faction of the) Targaryens promised that a Targaryen princess would marry into the Stark family.  This deal was known as the "Pact of Ice and Fire".

Yet, the Targaryens never fulfilled this promise, despite Cregan keeping up his end of the bargain.  Why did no Targaryen princess every marry into the Starks?

Comment: Since the one who made the promise were dead and Stark ended up just executing a bunch of people before taking his ball and going home.... I don't think anyone was going to force the issue.

Comment: Yet the non marriage parts of the past appear to have been kept https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Cregan_Stark

Answer (score 11):

Short answer: Jacaerys made the pact that he'd marry his firstborn daughter to Lord Cregan's heir. Jacaerys died without siring the said daughter. So did his mother, who bid Jacaerys to ask for Stark's help. Stark himself didn't seem interested at all in asking for the hand of the remaining Targaryen females which were King Aegon III's elder sisters.

Long Answer:

In addition to System down's answer, there are following factors to consider:

#### Who made the pact and what was it?

Prince Jacaerys Velaryon made the pact on behalf of his mother Rhaenyra Targaryen. As it happened however, when Lord Stark arrived, the war was over.

The man who made the promise was dead, the woman who sent that man was also dead. The Princess who was promised was never born. Aegon II ruled the city as anointed King until his assassination shortly before Lord Stark's arrival.

Neither the Crown nor the head of House Targaryen made that pact, both of those positions were held by Aegon II and afterwards Aegon III.

The pact was that even though Prince Jacaerys was unwed and childless at the moment, after his marriage and birth of his firstborn daughter, he'd send the Princess to Winterfell to be betrothed to Lord Stark's son and stay there as a ward. Since Prince Jacaerys died childless, there was no question of upholding the pact.

> “This we do know: Cregan Stark and Jacaerys Velaryon reached an
> accord, and signed and sealed the agreement that Grand Maester Munkun
> calls “the Pact of Ice and Fire” in his True Telling. Like many such
> pacts, it was to be sealed with a marriage. Lord Cregan’s son, Rickon,
> was a year old. Prince Jacaerys was as yet unmarried and childless,
> but it was assumed that he would sire children of his own once his
> mother sat the Iron Throne. Under the terms of the pact, the prince’s
> firstborn daughter would be sent north at the age of seven, to be
> fostered at Winterfell until such time as she was old enough to marry
> Lord Cregan’s heir.” 
> <sub>**George R. R. Martin. “Fire &
> Blood”**</sub>.

#### Aegon III's enthronement

Aegon III took the throne as heir and successor of his uncle Aegon II, not as heir of his mother Rhaenyra.

Aegon II's both sons had predeceased him. Prince Jaehaerys was slain by Blood and Cheese while Prince Maelor was killed by a mob.

Before his death, Aegon II passed an edict that in history and records, Rhaenyra should be referred as a Princess, not a Queen as she never was a Queen. The title Queen was to be reserved for his wife Helaena and mother Alicent.

> When his grief had passed, King Aegon II summoned his loyalists and
> made plans for his return to King’s Landing, to reclaim the Iron
> Throne and be reunited once again with his lady mother, the Queen
> Dowager, who had at last emerged triumphant over her great rival, if
> only by outliving her. **“Rhaenyra was never a queen,” the king
> declared, insisting that henceforth, in all chronicles and court
> records, his half sister be referred to only as “princess,” the title
> of queen being reserved only for his mother Alicent and his late
> wife** and sister Helaena, the “true queens.” And so it was decreed.
> <sub>***The Princess and the Queen***</sub>

At that time, Aegon III was the last Targaryen male other than his uncle. (No one knew his brother Viserys was alive in Lys).

When Aegon II was murdered, Aegon III took the throne as heir to his uncle, even though Princess Jaehaera was still alive, as the closest male kin. The rival factions made their peace by marrying Aegon III and Jaehaera, as Aegon III was representative of Blacks and Jaehaera would be the representative of Greens as last living child of Aegon II.

So System Down's point is valid. Rhaenyra lost the war and her life and any promises she made were no longer binding as King Aegon III inherited the throne from his uncle legally, not through the force of Arms of Starks.

Aegon III himself didn't see himself as heir of "Queen" Rhaenyra, rather heir of Aegon II. This is evident by the fact that Aegon III never reversed the edict of his uncle that Rhaenyra was never a Queen. His sons Daeron I and Baelor didn't reverse it either. Nor did Rhaenyra's younger son Viserys II or his son Aegon IV. None of the Targaryen monarchs<sup>1</sup> after Aegon II reversed it even though all were descended from Rhaenyra, not Aegon II.

#### Stark's own perception of Legal King and the Rebel

Cregan Stark himself recognized Aegon II as the rightful King by divine rights. That was his sole rationale for arresting people in *Hour of the Wolf* that it's one thing to slay a cruel unjust King in lawful battle and another to murder him with poison. So while he saw Aegon II as cruel and unjust, he recognized him as rightful King and therefore, by extension, admitted that Rhaenyra was a rebel and a pretender since both Rhaenyra and Aegon II couldn't be rightful monarchs simultaneously.

> Yet in one thing, Lord Stark would not be dissuaded: **the betrayers
> and poisoners of King Aegon II must pay the price. To kill a cruel and
> unjust king in lawful battle was one thing. But foul murder, and the
> use of poison, was a betrayal against the very gods who had anointed
> him**. Cregan had twenty-two men arrested in Aegon III's name—among
> them Larys Clubfoot and Corlys Velaryon. Cowed, the young Aegon
> III—who was eleven at the time—agreed to make Lord Stark his Hand.
> <sub>***TWOIAF - The Dragon Kings: Aegon III***</sub>

Fire & Blood provides us more information as to what Lord Stark thought. He considered Aegon II a usurper but accepted the usurpation as fait accompli and called Aegon II the King, regardless of him being an oathbreaker, Kinslayer and usurper.

> “Though Cregan Stark had no personal history with the Sea Snake, for
> good or ill, he knew that Lord Corlys had served Rhaenyra as Queen’s
> Hand, that she had imprisoned him on suspicion of treason, that he had
> been freed by Aegon II and accepted a seat upon his council…only, it
> would seem, to help bring about his death by poison. “Small wonder you
> are called the Sea Snake,” Lord Stark went on. “You may slither this
> way and that way but, oh, your fangs are venomous. Aegon was an
> oathbreaker, a kinslayer, and a usurper, yet still a King. When he would
> not heed your craven’s counsel, you removed him as a craven would,
> dishonorably, with poison…and now you shall answer for it.”
>
> <sub>**George R. R. Martin. “Fire & Blood”**</sub>.

#### Remaining Targaryen Princesses

At that time, only three Targaryen Princesses were alive:

1. Princess Jaehaera Targaryen, daughter of Aegon II and Queen of Aegon III.
2. Princess Rhaena Targaryen, daughter of Prince Daemon and sister to Aegon III.
3. Princess Baela Targaryen, daughter of Prince Daemon and sister to Aegon III

Jaehaera was already married to Aegon III and was the mortar that held the Greens and Blacks together. Cregan couldn't obviously marry her, not without causing a great scandal at least.

Rhaena and Baela were working ferociously to undo Lord Stark's orders of arresting and trying their grand-father Lord Corlys Velaryon for treason. They convinced their brother to pardon and order release of their Grandfather but it was one thing to get a royal order and another to have it implemented.

Real power was in hand of Lord Stark. The twin Princesses presumably made a deal with Lord Stark to let their Brother's orders stand, aided by their erstwhile ally, Lady Alysanne Blackwood. They didn't offer themselves in marriage, instead they offered Alysanne "Black Aly" Blackwood.

> Cregan Stark served in that office for a single day, presiding over
> the trials and executions. Most of the accused took the black (led by
> the cunning Ser Perkin the Flea). Two alone chose death—Ser Gyles
> Belgrave of the Kingsguard, who did not wish to outlive his king, and
> Larys the Clubfoot, the last of the ancient line of House Strong.
>
> **Lord Corlys was spared a trial by the machinations of Baela and Rhaena Targaryen, who convinced Aegon to issue an edict restoring to
> him his offices and honors, then by Black Aly Blackwood when she gave
> Lord Stark her hand in marriage in return for the boon of allowing
> Aegon's edict to stand**.
>
> **The day after the executions, Lord Stark resigned as Hand**.
> <sub>***TWOIAF - The Dragon Kings: Aegon III***</sub>

Worth noting, Princess Rhaena had a dragon. If someone wanted her hand or her sister's hand against their wishes, they could discuss it with [*Morning*](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Morning)<sup>2</sup>

Fire & Blood gives us an exact account of the negotiations. The topic of a Targaryen bride never came up. Lord Stark had come to be infatuated with Lady Alysanne Blackwood and she used it to her advantage. She asked the Lord Hand to pardon Corlys Velaryon for her sake and promised to do whatever he asked of her in return. Lord Stark asked her hand in marriage in return and Lady Alysanne consented. The match with either of the Princesses never came up and the Lord Regents were loathe to let any influential man marry them due to fears that if Aegon died, his sisters (Or their sons if they were born before Aegon's death) would be the heirs to the throne and if powerful men were chosen as the Prince consorts, they might turn the Princesses into nominal figureheads.

> “And so when Lady Alysanne came to ask that he let the prince’s edict
> stand, he listened. “Why would I do that?” Lord Stark purportedly
> asked when she had made her plea.
>
> “For the realm,” she answered.
>
> “It is better for the realm that traitors die,” he said.
>
> “For the honor of our prince,” said she.
>
> “The prince is a child. He ought not have meddled in this. It is
> Velaryon who brought dishonor on him, for now it will be said until
> the end of days that he came to his throne by murder.”
>
> “For the sake of peace,” said Lady Alysanne, “for all those who will
> surely die should Alyn Velaryon seek vengeance.”
>
> “There are worse ways to die. Winter has come, my lady.”
>
> “For me, then,” said Black Aly. “Grant me this boon, and I shall never
> ask another. Do this, and I shall know that you are as wise as you are
> strong, as kind as you are fierce. Give me this, and I shall give you
> whatever you may choose to ask of me.”
>
> Mushroom says Lord Cregan scowled at that. “What if I ask you for your
> maidenhead, my lady?”
>
> “I cannot give you what I do not have, my lord,” she answered. “I lost
> my maidenhead in the saddle when I was three-and-ten.”
>
> “Some would say that you squandered on a horse a gift that by rights
> should have belonged to your future husband.”
>
> “Some are fools,” Black Aly answered, “and she was a good horse,
> better than most husbands I have seen.”
>
> Her answer pleased Lord Cregan, who laughed aloud and said, “I shall
> try to remember that, my lady. Aye, I’ll grant your boon.”
>
> “And in return?” she asked.
>
> “All I ask is all of you, forever,” the Lord of Winterfell said
> solemnly. “I claim your hand in marriage.” 
> <sub>**George R. R.
> Martin. “Fire & Blood”**</sub>.

So clearly, Lord Stark was not at all interested in pressing the point that he was owed something a deadman promised.

#### Then why Uphold the non-Marital clauses of the Pact?

What makes you think that the rewards were because of the Pact?

> We have earlier discussed House Stark's role in the Dance of the
> Dragons. Let it be added that **Lord Cregan Stark reaped many rewards**
> **for his loyal support of King Aegon III**...even if it was not a royal
> princess marrying into his family, as had been agreed in the Pact of
> Ice and Fire made when the doomed prince Jacaerys Velaryon had flown
> to Winterfell upon his dragon.
> <sub>***TWOIAF - The North: Lords of Winterfell***</sub>

Note, he received the rewards for supporting King Aegon III, not for supporting Rhaenyra Targaryen. Aegon III wanted his Northern Warden to be loyal, so appeasement in form of money and honors wouldn't go amiss. The realm was still torn after a horrific civil war, His Grace needed his Lords behind him.

It is merely a note that while Cregan Stark eventually got most of what he was promised, a Targaryen Princess wasn't one of them. King Aegon III never left a record that the rewards were for Cregan's support for his mother's cause, but rather because Lord Stark supported the Young King himself.

---

<sub>1. The monarchs in question are Aegon III, Daeron I, Baelor, Viserys II, Aegon IV, Daeron II, Aerys I, Maekar, Aegon V, Jaehaerys II and Aerys II.</sub>

<sub>2. The Dragon was alive but very young. It was so small that Princess Rhaena used to carry it around on her shoulder.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

The pact was made between the Starks and the Black faction of the Dance of the Dragons. Since Queen Rhaenyra Targaryen was ultimately defeated in the conflict, the Blacks were now regarded as nothing more than rebels and thus any promises made by them were not recognized by the Iron Throne. If they had won, then the Starks would have probably claimed their part of the pact.

Comment: Rhaenyra's supporters won the  war though, installing Aegon III, and the Starks were rewarded for their support of the blacks. Your answer is in direct contradiction with the test.

Comment: Further to that, Aegon 3 rewarded Cregan for his loyalty with everything except the marriage